# Windows 11, Powershell and Windows Terminal Missing from Win+X Power User Menu

Tags: powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, windows-11

My problem is that I was missing the `Win+X, I` and `Win+X, A` shortcuts for opening Windows Terminal (Powershell) on Windows 11.  I checked my user's WinX directory and both Powershell and Command Prompt shortcuts were there, they just weren't displayed in the menu.

This appears to be a known issue but the only solutions I found involved downloading .zip files from a forum or pasting code snippets into Powershell, or a clean install of Win 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead, here's a super quick fix.

### Copy the correct shortcuts from the Default user in your own installation

Open an explorer window `Win+E` and navigate here:

```
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3
```

The WinX directory contains 3 folders, Group1, Group2, and Group3.  Each corresponds to the shortcuts that populate the 3 sections of the WinX menu.  Group3 from the Default user in the screenshot has the correct Windows Terminal Shortcuts.

[image: Default WinX Shortcuts]

### Paste correct shortcuts into your user's WinX dir

All you need to do is copy the contents of this folder over to your user's WinX directory here:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3
```

Let it replace any conflicting files when asked.

### Apply the changes

Either reboot, log out/in, or **restart** (not End) Windows Explorer Process for the changes to take effect.

[image: Task Manager Restart]

(If you accidentally end Explorer like, I did, and it doesn't restart on its own. From Task Manager click File > New Task and run `explorer.exe`.

Comment: To launch Explorer, it's enough to do *File > New Task* and run `explorer.exe`.

Comment: That's a good point @harrymc, I'll update with simplified instructions.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of completeness, if you're comfortable reading/running random powershell commands you find online...

u/Thotaz had this solution over on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/rksggc/comment/hpckpvl/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Running the commands below **will DELETE whatever is currently in your WinX shortcut directory**, so don't use them if you have any custom shortcuts.  Then it copies a fresh set of the shortcuts over from the Default User to your WinX Dir.

```
Remove-Item -Path $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\* -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
Copy-Item -Path C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\* -Destination $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\WinX -Container -Force -Recurse
```

You'll still need to reboot or restart the Explorer process to pick up the changes.